# Razor: How to force views in a folder, inherit from a special class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, razor, viewpage

I want to force views in a folder (for example folder associated with `ArticleController`, named `Article` in `View` directory) that inherits from a `CustomViewClass`. Note that I know how to change inheritance in `Razor` views, I do it. Now I want to change again for a special directory views. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a file in `Article` directory and name it `Web.config`
2. Copy and paste code below in it:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Your.NameSpace.CustomViewClass">
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

</configuration>
```

---

Now all views in `Article` directory, will inherit from `CustomViewClass`.